# Definition list accordion with unordered list control

Tags: javascript, jquery

as i found it the simple accordion at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LBC48/2/)
i want to add the control from the list menu, for example when i click the panel2 on unordered list, the Panel2 at dt is clicked (Expand too), any suggestion . Thanks

```
<ul class="list" style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a href="#">Panel 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Panel 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Panel 3</a></li>
</ul>
<dl class="accordion">
<dt><a href="">Panel 1</a></dt>
<dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</dd>
<dt><a href="">Panel 2</a></dt>
<dd>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</dd>
<dt><a href="">Panel 3</a></dt>
<dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. </dd>
</dl>

(function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });
     $('.accordion dt a').first().click();

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your markup, I assume the order of items in `ul` and the order of items in the accordion are the same, if so then in the `ul li` click you are manually trigger a click event in the accordion header in the same index

```
(function ($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    var $as = $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
    $('.accordion dt a').first().click();

    $('.list li').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $as.eq($(this).index()).click();
    })

})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vbZ7G/)